# How to fix glitchiness in a SpriteKit game that has a lot of code and timers?

Tags: xcode, swift

My game kind of stutters every now and then. In SpriteKit I think it's because of all the timers but Xcode still should be able to handle ten timers in using Xcode 6 and above.

Comment: You should post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: Xcode is not a language, nor a run time environment. It's an IDE, and attributing this to Xcode is no more accurate than attributing it to Safari, or Finder, or for that matter Windows 95.